# Error - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/Capabilities

Tags: java, selenium

What *.jar files are required to run the below code in Java?

```
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class OpenBrowser {
    //@SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FirefoxDriver w1=new FirefoxDriver();
        w1.get("https://google.com");
    }
}
```

Here is the error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/Capabilities
    at OpenBrowser.main(OpenBrowser.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.Capabilities
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 1):

That depends.

If you use [Maven](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/maven.jsp) in your project, then `selenium-java-*.jar` is sufficient.

If you have a standalone project, then you will probably want `selenium-server-standalone-*.jar`.